# Plural Adjectives Ending

Tags: english-to-german

"Oh du alter Mann, Oh du alte Frau, Oh, du kleines Kind. BUT: Oh, ihr alten Bauern. Question: Why not "Oh, Ihr alte Bauern"?

Comment: Why do you think it has to be "alte"?

Comment: Why? Because I looked for a chart for what we call "Vocative Case" and I am told I should follow the Nominative Case. Then I decided it should be a strong adjective ending, because the three examples I gave of singular M, F md N are all singular and follow the strong adjective endings.  They do that because there is no article that carries the case marker. If I write "alten," I am shifting to the weak adjective endings.

Comment: David, your answer led me to the discussion I was looking for! Duden is a bit advanced for me but I will try to read that too. Thank you!

Comment: It's not »Oh«, but »O«. Wrong: *»Oh du alter Mann!«* Correct: *»**O** du alter Mann!«* The word *»o«* is a vocative marker and is used in salutations. The word *»oh«* also exists, but it is an interjection (*»Oh, das wollte ich nicht.«*) For example the title of the famous Christmas carol is not  *»Oh Tannenbaum«* but *»**O** Tannenbaum«.* Btw: It's exactly the same as in English.